# log15 library rounds up epoch time from nanoseconds to seconds for logging

Tags: unix, go, logging, time, epoch

I'd like to have millisecond precision for my logging in my golang project, currently using log15 library

Problem is when I append it to Context, it rounds back up to seconds

```
newTimeWithMilliseconds := time.Unix(0, time.Now().UnixNano())

return log.FuncHandler(func(r *log.Record) {
     r.Ctx = append(r.Ctx, "time", newTimeWithMilliseconds)
     nextHandler.Log(r)
})
```

When I convert it to string `newTimeWithMilliseconds.String()` it works and I get `"2018-09-25 15:07:45.25801232 -0500 PDT"`, but when I don't, the decimals go away and I get `2018-09-25 15:07:45 -0700 PDT`.

I want to keep in Time format though and not use string, anybody have any ideas on why this is happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to display your `time.Time`'s value with the precision you want. It doesn't loose its precision unless you modify its value, the reason why you see a difference is only due to the `layout` used by the call for `time.Format` of whatever is printing your time.

When you use `mytime.String()`, the layout used is different that the one used by whatever prints your time otherwise.

That's why you need to either use the `time.Time` value but manipulate the way it is printed, or store it as a formatted string instead.

See [Go by example](https://gobyexample.com/time-formatting-parsing)

```
// Go supports time formatting and parsing via
// pattern-based layouts.

package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    p := fmt.Println

    // Here's a basic example of formatting a time
    // according to RFC3339, using the corresponding layout
    // constant.
    t := time.Now()
    p(t.Format(time.RFC3339))

    // Time parsing uses the same layout values as `Format`.
    t1, e := time.Parse(
        time.RFC3339,
        "2012-11-01T22:08:41+00:00")
    p(t1)

    // `Format` and `Parse` use example-based layouts. Usually
    // you'll use a constant from `time` for these layouts, but
    // you can also supply custom layouts. Layouts must use the
    // reference time `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` to show the
    // pattern with which to format/parse a given time/string.
    // The example time must be exactly as shown: the year 2006,
    // 15 for the hour, Monday for the day of the week, etc.
    p(t.Format("3:04PM"))
    p(t.Format("Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"))
    p(t.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999-07:00"))
    form := "3 04 PM"
    t2, e := time.Parse(form, "8 41 PM")
    p(t2)

    // For purely numeric representations you can also
    // use standard string formatting with the extracted
    // components of the time value.
    fmt.Printf("%d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d-00:00\n",
        t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(),
        t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second())

    // `Parse` will return an error on malformed input
    // explaining the parsing problem.
    ansic := "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
    _, e = time.Parse(ansic, "8:41PM")
    p(e)
}
```

Outputs

```
2009-11-10T23:00:00Z
2012-11-01 22:08:41 +0000 UTC
11:00PM
Tue Nov 10 23:00:00 2009
2009-11-10T23:00:00+00:00
0000-01-01 20:41:00 +0000 UTC
2009-11-10T23:00:00-00:00
parsing time "8:41PM" as "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006": cannot parse "8:41PM" as "Mon"
```

Try it out yourself [here](https://play.golang.org/p/BFw556nWcM)

Comment: time.Format returns a string, I want to use the actual Time type, not a string

Comment: If you use it as a `time.Time`, unless you modified it, it should still have the same precision. I guess that the difference you observe is in the way you print it. Calling `.String()` on your `time.Time` formats it in a way that displays the ms, while the other method you tried doesn't, because it uses a different format layout.

Comment: So again, if you wish to display a milisecond precision, you have to either pass a string instead of a time, formatted in the way you want, or to pass a `time.Time` and control the function that prints it by enforcing a format that is precise enough.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @user3226932 You do _not_ want an actual Time type--that's what you have and you're complaining about it.

Comment: so to solve this we can only change the time format constant in the logging library, golang context's Time only accepts a Time type, not a string

Comment: @user3226932 What do you mean "golang context's Time only accepts a Time type"? Go's context package, which is usually meant by a phrase like "golang's context", has no concept of Time at all.